# How to locate xpath for attached screenshot. In Java would be helpful

Tags: selenium

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bF1q7.png)

Can someone please help on this?

Comment: Add html code...

Answer (score 0):

```
webdriver.findElement(xpath("//div[@id = 'decisionSupport-header']/div[1]/button[1]/span[1]"))
```

Answer (score 0):

xpath is as below

```
//button[@type='button'][contains(.,'Details')]
```

java code is as below

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='button'][contains(.,'Details')]")
```